# Configure IAppBuilder outside of project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to create a method which will configure `IAppBuilder` in a different dll.  I am experimenting with Identity and Owin and I am just trying to understand how things work.

The following code works:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserService, User>(
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
           consumerKey: "",
           consumerSecret: ""
           );

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: "",
           appSecret: ""
        );

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = ""
        });

        app.UseSteamAuthentication("");
    }
}
```

What I wanted to do was this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app = new AppBuilderService.BuildApp(app);
    }
}
```

The code that I tried adding to `BuildApp` method:

```
public class AppBuilderService
{
    public IAppBuilder BuildApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserService, User>(
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
           consumerKey: "",
           consumerSecret: ""
           );

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: "",
           appSecret: ""
        );

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = ""
        });

        app.UseSteamAuthentication("");
    }

    return app;
}
```

As you can see the code is nearly identitcal.  The problem that I am having is that `CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType` is always red and visual studio cannot recognize and such cannot build it.  I can't seem to figure out what reference is missing as I have all the same using statements that I have in Startup.  VS is also not making any suggestions.

What reference am I missing to make this work?

Comment: `DefaultAuthenticationTypes` is part of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` found in `Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll, v2.0.0.0`

Comment: @Nkosi see I kept searching it in Owin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.authenticationoptions(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultAuthenticationTypes` is part of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` found in `Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll, v2.0.0.0`

It is primarily used by OWIN to enumerate the default authentication types associated with Microsoft ASP.NET Identity 2.0

[DefaultAuthenticationTypes Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.defaultauthenticationtypes(v=vs.108).aspx)